# DevExpress XtraGrid LayoutView - set card size

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

how can I set the card size in a layout view? I have googled a lot, but found nothing useful.

Please see the image below. I would like to increase the size of the images (the size mode of the pictureedit control is set to squeeze)

[image]

One more question: how can I hide the up-down button in a cell?

Comment: nobody knows the solution?

Comment: Have you tried this question with the DevExpress customer support? They give great answers, and the response time is very good if you are a subscription customer. If you want, you can send them a small sample and they will return it with the functionality you desire. You'll get much luckier than asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [LayoutView.CardMinSize](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsLayoutLayoutView_CardMinSizetopic) property specifies a card's minimum size. A card can have a larger size if individual field sizes are not fixed and are therefore variable in size, depending on their contents.
Related example: [How to create and customize a LayoutView in code](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3518)

You can hide up-down ([field sort buttons](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3448)) using a column's [OptionsColumn.AllowSort](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsOptionsColumn_AllowSorttopic) option.

P.S. I believe the best way to get **guaranteed assistance** with any DevExpress controls is contacting with [DevExpress Support](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center) directly. Note that FULL SUPPORT IS FREE during the evaluation period (30 days).

Comment: ok, the card size is now bigger. But the image size stayed the same. Basically, I would like to set the image size bigger.

Comment: You can customize the card's layout as you needed. Run the designer and 
customize the TemplateCard's items (widths/heights and relative locations). Please also take a look at LayoutView demos (for example Image Gallery)